# Angular - Render a template in a sibling component

Tags: angular, angular-template

I'm at a loss on how to accomplish this:

I want to define in a component, a section that will be rendered by a sibling component, but using the original component's context:
Imagine the following components: **A**, **B**, **C** and **side-panel**.

In the side panel I want to show a form that is **defined** in **A** **B** or **C**, so that when people are creating extra components they can define the options form that will be shown in the side panel.

For a static setup I could create a service to pass the data from the side panel into and out of my current active component (A, B, or C), but I think there might be a more flexible option with EmbeddedViewRef and templates that would truly scale well and would not require editing the side panel or the data passing service when the application is extended by a new component **D**.

app.component.html

```
<side-panel>
</side-panel>
<router-outlet></outlet>
```

In the side-panel component, I want to render options which change according to which component is being shown in the router-outlet

a.component.html

```
<div>
   {{option1 * 10}}
</div>
<ng-template #options>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="option1">
</ng-template>
```

I would like the #options template to be displayed in the side-panel component which is a sibling of A component.

When rendering a template you can inject a context object but I would like the context to be the same as A's context so that changes and options selected in the side panel affect A component.

Any help into what concepts I should read about would be much appreciated.

### Update:

Angular CDK Portals address precisely this problem. They allow for a component's template to be rendered in another place - a portalHost.
https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview

Comment: What do meane by "defined in A B or C"? I feel language is confusing.

Comment: Maybe it is, by defined in A B or C, I mean defined in A B or C own template code. As in A.component.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you want but I think you can use content projection to project component A, B or C within your Side-Panel component using the `<ng-content>` tag.

```
// side-panel component:
<ng-content></ng-content>

// app component
<app-side-panel>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</app-side-panel>
```

Here is a full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rzh9cw

**UPDATE:**
Reading your question again I think what you are having is a state management problem:

> I would like the #options template to be displayed in the side-panel component which is a sibling of A component.

```
<ng-template #options>
  <input type="number" [(ngModel)]="option1">
</ng-template>
```

Since `#options` template will affect the properties of component A both from inside and from outside the component, you need to define `#options` as a separated component so that you can reuse it in both places:

Options Component:

```
<input #input type="number" (change)="changeOption(input.value)">
```

Component A:

```
<div>
   {{option1 * 10}}
</div>
<app-options></app-options>
```

Side Panel Component:

```
<app-options></app-options>
```

Now, in order for OptionsComponent to make changes in Component A, you can use a service to store the state of these options you want to change and share across the app, that way components A, B or C can listen to it and react accordingly:

Options Service:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
class OptionsService {
  private options$ = new BehaviorSubject({
    option1: 1,
    option2: 'on',
    option3: 'blue'
  });

  public options: Observable<Options>;

  constructor() {
    this.options = this.options$.asObservable();
  }

  public changeOptions(options: Options) {
    this.options$.next(options);
  }
}
```

Options Component (Uses OptionsService to trigger changes):

```
constructor(private optionsService: OptionsService) {}

public changeOption(value): void {
  this.optionsService.changeOptions({
    option1: value,
    option2: 'off',
    option3: 'red'
  });
}
```

and finally Component A can subscribe to these changes:

```
constructor(private optionsService: OptionsService) {}

public ngOnInit() {
  this.optionsService.options.subscribe((options: Options) => {
    console.log(options);
    this.option1 = options.option1;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the effort. The issue is that I wished for the components to be rendered both outside of the side panel and inside the side panel simultaneously. And to share context so as to reflect changes across both locations. Imagine your properties tab in an image manipulation program. It changes the options based on the element you have selected. Here it should change based on the component being rendered in the router outlet.

Comment: So basically what you want is to render component A (or B or C) in multiple locations at the same time but keeping the same "state" of the component no matter where it's being rendered and update them all if any changes occur? if so then your problem seems to be more related to state management, which you can solve by using plain Angular Services or a state management library like NGRX (Redux pattern). Do you know about those?

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, because it accomplishes the functionality, but not the purpose. I am familiar with all of those, the thing is that I am trying to write a framework where the options are defined in the component itself. Say that some other developer wants to extend your components library by adding a component D. He will have to interface with the global object (through a global object or a state management service as you have mentioned) and I was hoping that I could do it self contained. I'll mark your answer as the solution if I don't come up with anything better in two days.

Comment: I couldn't accomplish this - Maybe it's just an anti pattern and it's an unworthwhile idea. Whoever writes the component should also write another component for the options and a common service can be used to register the data sharing mechanism. Thanks for all the help